# How does one sketch the graph of a function containing a limit, such as $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x^{n-1}+x^{n})^{1/n}$?

Tags: calculus

I know how to sketch the graph of ordinary functions, but am clueless when it comes to this one:

$f(x) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (1 + x^{n-1} + x^{n})^\frac{1}{n}$

for $x\ge0$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(1+x^{n-1}+x^n)^{1/n}=\exp\big(\frac{1}{n}\ln(1+x^{n-1}+x^n)\big)$.

Thus, if we set

$$g(n):=\frac{\ln(1+x^{n-1}+x^n)}{n}$$

we have

$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x^{n-1}+x^n)^{1/n}=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty} g(n)}$$

Now break your work into cases to study $\lim_{n\to\infty} g(n)$.

---

Assume $x>1$. Then, using L'Hopital's rule, the limit of $g(n)$ as $n\to\infty$ is

$$\frac{1}{1+x^{n-1}+x^n}\left(x^{n-1}\ln x+x^n\ln x\right)$$

and another application of L'Hopital's rule gives

$$\frac{x^{n-1}(\ln x)^2+x^n(\ln x)^2}{x^{n-1}\ln x+x^n\ln x}=\frac{x^{n-1}(\ln x)^2(1+x)}{x^{n-1}\ln x(1+x)}=\ln x$$

So in this case $f(x)=e^{\ln x}=x$.

---

Now suppose $0\leq x<1$. Then $x^{n-1}+x^n\to0$, so $g(n)\to0$, so $f(x)=e^0=1$.

---

Finally, I imagine you can handle the case $x=1$.